# Setting a MCU in low power mode on Linux

Tags: embedded-linux, interrupt, power-management, atmel

I'm running embedded Linux (Angstrom) on an Atmel board (at91 sam9g25) mounting an ARM MCU.

I'd like to set the CPU in idle mode, ideally from userspace by using a function (then the system would be waken up by an hardware gpio interrupt). How can I do that? Alternatively, how can it be done in kernelspace?
I cannot find much, maybe somebody has some example to start from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking this [page](http://www.spinics.net/lists/arm-kernel/msg59204.html) . Try also reading [Optimizing Power Consumption for AT91SAM9261-based Systems](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc6217.pdf) to have an idea about what you can do with power management.

What you can basically do is setting the state you want in `/sys/power/state` but before entering the low-power state you need to set how your system can be awakened.

Be advised that, in my experience, I have seen a lot of different behaviors by changing the kernel, so by patient and try different versions.

Comment: Even if setting /sys/power/state in "standby" sets the system in that mode (no response until it's woken up by some interrupt), I've noticed that its power consumption doesn't decrease at all, but stays at the "active mode" level (~130mA). Do you have any idea why?